# Is there a way to integrate git with Jupyter and have a version control over the notebooks created?

Tags: git, github, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I have hosted jupyterhub on a server and added many users into it. I want the users to have an option of version control for their work. So is there any way to add a git kernel or extension do have this done?

Comment: The current version offers some "checkpoint" mechanism, I guess that can be modified to use git _somehow_...

Answer (score 3):

You can version jupyter notebooks directly using [kyso.io](https://kyso.io) (disclaimer: I founded kyso).

Kyso supports the Jupyter format fully so you can render them nicely, and have proper versioning, diffing and merging of .ipynb files.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at " nbdime " project, Solves all the issues in visualizing the diff in big notebook

Answer (score 2):

Ipython notebook files (*.ipynb) are [actually view-able on Github](https://github.com/blog/1995-github-jupyter-notebooks-3)

You can simply add the notebook files to the Github repo like any other file, and use all of Git's version control features.

When I am working with people on a shared project, we have a single repo for the project and individually check in code using Git.

Answer (score 2):

JupyterHub has the ability to start Unix command line terminals via New, Terminal. `git` is available there via the command line interface. You may have to do some measure of `git` configuration to push out to github, etc.

Comment: awesome, this is what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Edit your notebook in Visual Studio Code using JupyterHub as a [remote server](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support#_connect-to-a-remote-jupyter-server) and [export to python when you are done](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/announcing-support-for-native-editing-of-jupyter-notebooks-in-vs-code/).

Comment: Hum, this is not an answer to the question. It asks about jupyter-git integration. 
Your proposal is not an integration.

Comment: @Natacha this isn't a direct answer to the question, but a possible solution for the problem. Maybe somebody will find useful. I added another link to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

Use jupyterlab-git:
https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git

It provides git integration for Jupyterlab:

[image]

Also see related question:
[How to init content of notbooks / working directory in Jupyterhub/Jupyterlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64485967/how-to-init-content-of-notbooks-working-directory-in-jupyterhub-jupyterlab)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this jupyter extension. It will enable you to directly upload your ipython notebooks to github.

https://github.com/sat28/githubcommit

I have also created a video demonstrating the steps -
[youtube link](https://youtu.be/vKx_4zFvOi8)